# Macro with _Pragma - parenthesis

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, pragma

I'd like to simplify some preprocessor code by creating appropriate macros. I'd like to wrap

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
    _Pragma("omp critical(stdout)")
#endif
```

into a single

```
_OMP_CRITICAL(stdout)
```

so I did

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
    #define STRINGIFY(x) #x
    #define _OMP_CRITICAL(x)    _Pragma(STRINGIFY(omp critical(x)))
#else
    #define _OMP_CRITICAL(x)
#endif
```

Will it expand into what I expect? What will be passed to `STRINGIFY` as an "argument"? `omp critical(x value)`, or maybe `omp critical(x value`? Are parenthesis matched in this situation?

A program works correctly. But I do not understand macros well, so it could possibly produce some compiling code, which will sometimes work, sometimes not. Parallel things are weird, as you probably know, so I want to make sure it is correct.

Comment: Have you I dunno, tried running it?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, I did. It worked. But I do not understand macros well, so it could possibly produce some compiling code, which will sometimes work, sometimes not. Parallel things are weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has to be matched correctly. To quote [C11 (n1750) §6.10.3 ¶10](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3p10) (emphasis mine):

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # define identifier lparen identifier-listopt ) replacement-list new-line
> # define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line
> # define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line
> ```
>
> defines a function-like macro with parameters, whose use is similar
>   syntactically to a function call. The parameters are specified by the
>   optional list of identifiers, whose scope extends from their
>   declaration in the identifier list until the new-line character that
>   terminates the #define preprocessing directive. Each subsequent
>   instance of the function-like macro name followed by a ( as the next
>   preprocessing token introduces the sequence of preprocessing tokens
>   that is replaced by the replacement list in the definition (an
>   invocation of the macro). **The replaced sequence of preprocessing
>   tokens is terminated by the matching ) preprocessing token, skipping
>   intervening matched pairs of left and right parenthesis preprocessing
>   tokens**. Within the sequence of preprocessing tokens making up an
>   invocation of a function-like macro, new-line is considered a normal
>   white-space character.

Comment: This is the advantage of _Pragma vs #pragma. The former is not a preprocessor directive so all kind of preprocesor tricks can be done to it.